# Is it possible to download images contained in an Excel document using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I want to download an image contained in an Excel sheet cell. Are there any NodeJS packages I can use to access this images? I'm already using the [XLSX package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) for downloading Excel sheet contents.

Answer (score -1):

XLSX files are secretly zipped up XML documents :D! Just unzip them using your favorite ZIP tool to get a folder containing all the images and other content in your excel document.

Look at [node-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-zip) and [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) to do this in node.